# Firefox can't override "<input> picker was blocked due to lack of user activation" in about:config

Tags: javascript, firefox

When I try to programmatically click a file upload button in Firefox with `document.getElementById['myId'].click()`, I get

> picker was blocked due to lack of user activation.

I see in the [Firefox source code](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/locales/en-US/chrome/dom/dom.properties)

> InputPickerBlockedNoUserActivation= picker was blocked due to lack of user activation

in the console. I tried setting `InputPickerBlockedNoUserActivation` to `false` in `about:config`. This has no effect, and I'm still blocked.

Is there a way to override the block on `.click()`, or is there something I'm not understanding about `InputPickerBlockedNoUserActivation`?

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough and contrary to common sense when I set
`InputPickerBlockedNoUserActivation` in `about:config` programmatic `.click()` magically started to work no matter if the state is `true` or `false`.

Comment: i had to set it to true for it to work for me.